# jqm subpage events catching

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page and a sub page in jqm.
subpage is a form. I want populate the current date in a date input text box when the subpage is loaded.
I am confused with this subpage. I am new to subpages.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out populating date.
but still find it hard to find out catching sub page load event.
I presume there is no load event for sub page.
May b God knows....
trying on other workarounds